# Using non-typescript npm package (pondjs) with Meteor from typescript files

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, npm, angular2-meteor

I added the Pondjs library to my project with:

```
meteor npm install --save pondjs
```

But I can't figure out how to use it within my Typescript files,

The [documentation](http://software.es.net/pond/#/start?_k=zbczck) says:

> To use it within a browser you will need to install it with npm and then build your source with Webpack, Browserify or something similar.

But since I am using (Angular2-)Meteor I can't use Webpack or Browserify.

I tried importing as:

```
import 'pondjs'; // no complaint about import

declare var Index: any;
let index = new Index("1d-12345"); //but: Can't find variable: Index
```

Also:

```
import * as something from 'pondjs'; // cannot find module 'pondjs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the the typescript compiler cannot find the module because there are no typings. However the package can still be used with ES6 imports:

```
import {Index, TimeSeries} from "pondjs";
```

Meteor will find the package and send it to the browser. So just ignore the compiler error or write typings.